# Turn a slug into an id

Tags: php, oop, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am quite new to Symfony and Doctrine and I'm trying to work out how I can get the following route to convert to an id so I don't have to search by strings all the time (unless that is considered to be fine these days?)

So for example I want `/my_app/category/subcategory/page` to be readable by my controller as 
`/my_app/3/2/1` so I can use `->find($id)` instead of having to use `-findBySlug($slug)`.

How do I do this?

Comment: What is wrong with this?

Comment: It doesn't seem to like using anything other than id's when using entity relationships. At least, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

In your routing file:

```
your_route_name:
    pattern: /my_app/{category}/{subcategory}/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: YourBundle:YourController:FindPost }
```

In your controller:

```
public function FindPostAction($category, $subcategory, $page)
{
    //...use $category, $subcategory, $page here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I've explained myself very clearly. I don't need to know how to use routing. I need to know how to make a controller see a string url as an integer url.

So that '/business' is read by the controller as '1'.

Comment: When you generate the route above, for example in twig, pass category, subcategory and page ids to the path function:

Comment: Passing the id in the path is not an option I'm afraid. Besides I was under the impression that exposing id's to the public is bad practice?

Comment: what do you want those numbers to represent then?

Comment: Ok so in the database I have a table which contains my content. In that table is a field called 'categoryId'. Lets say there is a row where the contents name is 'hello-world' and the category is set to 1.

There is also a table which contains a list of all the categories, there are 2 fields: 'id' and 'categoryName'. The row with an id of 1 has a name of 'Business'. 

I want to create a db search which will find all posts under the business category but NOT include the category or post id's in the URL.

Comment: I don't see how you could use numbers in URLs without using ids. You could add additional field for numeric identifier of the record, which is basically the same as an id. You can probably do some calculations on the number in order to hide its original value. For example, you can do series of arithmetic operations on id. You would "encode" it when generating URL, and "decode" it right before plugin it into find().

Comment: I still don't think I'm explaining myself clearly. I don't want numbers in the URL. It's ok. I'm sure I'll figure it out.